# powercfg set AC and DC

Tags: salt-stack

Can someone let me know how to set powercfg on windows using saltstack for AC and DC?

```
monitor:
   powercfg.set_timeout:
    - value: 30
    - power: dc
```

This will set for monitor DC, but how to add for monitor AC if I cannot use another ID and ID cannot duplicate in the state?

Doc: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/3004/ref/states/all/salt.states.win_powercfg.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot use another ID

Yes you can:

```yaml
monitor dc:
  powercfg.set_timeout:
    - name: monitor
    - value: 30
    - power: dc

monitor ac:
  powercfg.set_timeout:
    - name: monitor
    - value: 120
    - power: ac
```